# REST authorization with exteral roles

Tags: java, spring, security, authorization, interceptor

I have a scenario where I have roles and permissions in a different system (where i need to make a REST call) and that system will specify whether I can access a particular resource or not.

I need to intercept my controller methods and that Interceptor should talk to external service and figure out the authorization. I am using just spring boot (no spring security).

It should be similar to this [with JAX-RS](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/26/jax-rs-resteasy-basic-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial/) but I'm looking in spring context. Can I achieve this using `@RolesAllowed`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to hopefully better reflect your intent and cleaned it up just a bit  :)   If you think I've changed your intent, feel free to revert the edit. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an interceptor:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a configuration that you will annotate with (check spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html))

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
```

Then you will have to create your own access decision manager and register your own roles. With this you should be able to annotate your controllers to a specific user like `@RolesAllowed("admin")`